Linear independence of elementary symmetric functions over the ring of polynomials
Let $R:=\mathbb{C}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ and $R_{\text{Sym}}$ denote the ring of symmetric polynomials in $x_{1},\ldots,x_{n}$ over $\mathbb{C}$. Consider the elementary symmetric polynomials $e_1,\ldots,e_n$. While working on a problem I came across the following question: is there a relation of the form $c_{1}e_{1}+\ldots+c_{n}e_{n}$, where $c_{i}\in R$ for all $i$ and not all $c_{i}$'s are zero.
P.S: By the fundamental theorem on symmetric polynomials, we know that $e_1,\ldots,e_n$ are algebraically independent over $\mathbb{C}$. However, the above question is different than the stated theorem.

Hint: assume that there is a linear relation and try to plug some values of $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ to get some equations (e.g. start with $(1,0,\ldots,0)$). Alternatively, one can argue the linear independence using the degree of $e_i$'s.

@richrow I tried following your hint but I got stuck. Here's what I thought so far: wlog we may assume that $c_{i}$'s are homogeneous of correct degree, i.e, if deg$(c_{1})=m$, then deg$(c_{i})=m+1-i$. First we want to show $c_{1}=0$. For this, we substitute the $i$-th coordinate vectors, which gives us that the coefficient of $x_{j}^{m}$ in $c_{1}$ is $0$ for all $j$. However, I am unable to show why the coefficients of other monomials in $c_{1}$ are all $0$.

@richrow: I don't understand this hint, and in fact the $e_i$ clearly seem linearly dependent to me. Can't we just take e.g. $c_1 = - e_2, c_2 = e_1$?

@QiaochuYuan Thanks, they are clearly linearly dependent.

@QiaochuYuan Right, I misread the question and thought that we are required to show the linear independence over $\mathbb{C}$. Otherwise, it is clearly false, as you indicated.
